# Using apollo and graphql higher order component to paginate data

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo, apollo-client

I have a simple component that fetches book titles

```
export const books = gql`
  query Query {
    books {
      title
    }
  }
`

export default graphql(books)(BookList)
```

Api I am using itself doesn't have any sort of pagination mechanism specified, but I am wondering if apollo / graphql provides one out of the box, if it does what is the correct way to paginate data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `skip` and `last` in your query

`skip` - no of record wants to skip

`last` - id of last record from previous records

```
export const books = gql`
  query Query {
    books(skip:10, last: '\\any valid id') {
      title
   }
}
```

hope this will help